# write data into excel using powershell from sql table

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a .xlsx file which was made into data table by oledb provider.Now I want to add value to that .xlsx based on the sql table data I have
(which is also converted into a csv file `Book1.csv`)

The sql table consists of name and notes...
Where name column is same in both .xlsx file and sql variable `$sql`

I want to add that close notes to `f` column of .xlsx file if the value of name matches with the value of sql table "A" column One I wrote below is very slow and not effective.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\VIKRAM\Documents\Sample - Superstore.xlsx')
$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$WorkSheet.Name
$Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find('$Data.number')
$Found.row
$Found.text
$Excel1 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$file = $Excel1.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\VIKRAM\Documents\Book1.xlsx')
$ff=$file.Sheets.Item(1)
$ff.Name
$ff1=$ff.Range("A1").entirecolumn
$ff1.Value2

foreach ($line in $ff1.value2){

if( $found.text -eq $line)
{
    Write-Host "success"
    $fff=$ff1.Row   
    $WorkSheet.Cells.item($fff,20) =$ff.cells.item($fff,2)
}
}
```

Data in .xlsx file

```
Number  Priority  Comment
612721  4 - High
```

Data in Book1.csv

```
Number Clo_notes
612721 Order has been closed
```

I need to update clo_notes value to comment in .xlsx file if this "number" column in each file matches update the clos_notes to the corresponding column of comment

Comment: Have you looked into the `ImportExcel` module? `Install-Module ImportExcel `: [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/)

Comment: @jrider Challenge is I was not able to install any module in my environment due to security constraints.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what has `Nebraska` to do with the structure of your data`?

Comment: @LotPings Sorry typo, edited it

Comment: That raises the question how `$Data.Number`is defined at the point you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you answered my question about where "Nebraska" falls into the data.

Make sure to release any COM objects, or you'll have orphaned Excel processes.

You might try something like this. I was able to write the Clo_notes value into column 6 as you were requesting:

```
## function to close all com objects
function Release-Ref ($ref) {
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

## open Excel data
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\51290\Documents\_temp\StackOverflowAnswers\Excel.xlsx')
$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$WorkSheet.Name

## open SQL data
$Excel1 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$file = $Excel1.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\51290\Documents\_temp\StackOverflowAnswers\SQL.xlsx')
$sheetSQL = $file.Sheets.Item(1)
$dataSQL = $sheetSQL.Range("A1").currentregion

$foundNumber = 0
$row_idx = 1
foreach ($row in $WorkSheet.Rows) {
    "row_idx = " + $row_idx
    if ($row_idx -gt 1) {
        $foundNumber = $row.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2
        "foundNumber = " + $foundNumber

        if ($foundNumber -eq "" -or $foundNumber -eq $null) {
            Break
        }

        foreach ($cell in $dataSQL.Cells) {
            if ($cell.Row -gt 1) {
                if ($cell.Column -eq 1 -and $cell.Value2 -eq $foundNumber) {
                    $clo_notes = $sheetSQL.Cells.Item($cell.Row, 2).Value2
                    Write-Host "success"
                    $WorkSheet.Cells.item($row_idx, 6).Value2 = $clo_notes
                }

            }

        }
    }
    $row_idx++
}


$Excel.Quit()
$Excel1.Quit()

## close all object references
Release-Ref($WorkSheet)
Release-Ref($WorkBook)
Release-Ref($Excel)
Release-Ref($Excel1)
```

Comment: Yes this logic helps!!...what if there are 10 rows?how to increment it

Comment: Yes this logic helps!!...what if there are 10 rows?how to increment it

Comment: I modified the logic to loop through the "Excel" data and find the Number column in the "SQL" data. I'm not an expert with the Range object in Excel, so there's probably a better/faster way to approach this.